# NgMap Angular Markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps

I was implementing Ng-Map for angular for my application. So I retrieve entries from the database and try to drop markers. But the problem is I have around 40 entries and only first 11 show up in the marker. I checked and all the 40 coaches are present in the model.coaches. All the remaining get displayed on the centre of the map. My application has filters for location. So if I add filter for a particular location all the markers show up for that location but once I remove it only the first 11 show up. What is wrong?

```
    <ng-map center="37.09024, -95.712891" zoom="4" mayTypeId="ROADMAP"
style="height: 88%; width: 100%" styles="{{model.styles}}"
                    pan-control="false"
                    map-type-control="false"
                    map-type-control-options="false"
                    zoom-control="true"
                    zoom-control-options="false">


                <marker ng-repeat="coach in model.coaches track by $index"
                        id="{{$index}}"
                        position="{{coach.Town}} {{coach.State}}{{coach.Zipcode}}"
                        on-mouseover="model.showinfowindow(event,$index)"
                        on-mouseout="model.hideinfowindow()"
                        on-click="model.viewMapProfile(coach)">
                </marker>


                <info-window id="foo">
                    <div ng-non-bindable="" align="center" class="mapViewProfile" style="padding-left: 20px">
                        {{model.coach.name}}<br>
                        {{model.coach.schoolName}}
                    </div>
                </info-window>

            </ng-map>
```

Comment: Looks like a throttling issue. Do you know if any service like geocoding is used internally?

Comment: @xomena In my code? Or the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `position="{{coach.Town}} {{coach.State}}{{coach.Zipcode}}"` I understand that somewhere in directive you have to resolve the string address to coordinate.

To resolve the string to coordinate you should execute the geocoding service request. Maps JavaScript API initially has a bucket of 10 geocoding requests, once this bucket used you can execute requests at rate 1 request per second. So you have 10 markers from initial bucket + 1 request and everything else return OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

ng-repeat in this case executes geocoding requests faster than it is allowed by API.

Comment: so what is to be done? so as my all 40 markers show up.

Comment: Thanks ! You were right! Storing the coordinates in the database worked!